# Unexpected $scope.var behaviour

Tags: angularjs

I've found a problem in my code... I've tried to debug and ended up doing something as simple as:

```
$scope.activity = {
    subject:          null,
    activity_type_id: null,
    description:      null,
    date:             null,
    time:             null,
    duration:         null,
    set_as_done:      false,
    attaches: {
        company:  'test',
        people:   null,
        deal:     null
    }
};

console.log($scope.activity);
```

When printing into the console, I get "NULL" instead of "test" in $scope.activity.attaches.company...

However, If I print

```
console.log($scope.activity.attaches)
```

I get the right value... Completely lost at the moment...

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Even more worried, seems to work perfect in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bL4rd/